# Access files with client that are bind mounted on server "into" NFS share

Tags: nfs, network-share, mount

I have a home server, with multiple drives, for simplicity sake
/media/user/Photos
/media/user/Software

Both of which are seperatly exported NFS

Then 1 single directory "/media/user/Software/software" containing a bunch of....well software and what not.

Saddly the drive mounted at/media/user/Software just failed, I had a backup of the info. I put this back up in /media/user/Photos/software

Now I have lots of apps that are set up to look to /media/user/Software/software for configs and even some binaries. I wanted to still be able to access them for a few weeks/months while I save up to buy a new drive to replace the other.

First I just made a symlink, that works great locally, but as you know doesnt do so well on remote systems.

Then I thought I could bind mount it and that would work so on the server I did

```
sudo mount --bind /media/ketterer/Photos/software/ /media/ketterer/Software/software/
```

Again this worked great locally but didnt work like I thought it would for my remote clients, I thought that a bind mount duplicated the directory tree so I thought id be able to access the files from remotly "through" the original path.

Where am I going wrong? or what is a better way to do what I want? could it be an NFS export issue or is this just not possible?

Comment: I think you should straighten up this question a bit. It's very long, and people will just not read it. You experiences and your expectations are not separated, and you didn't define your problem better than 'it does not work, why?'. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I assume */media/ketterer/Photos* and */media/ketterer/Software* are separate exports on the server.
You can use `showmount -e <nfs-server-ip>` or on the server `exportfs -v` to show/verify the exports.

You would have to specify the `crossmnt` on the server to make the bind mounted directory visible.

Assuming `/media/ketterer/Photos` is the exported path, adopt the NFS export configuration and add `crossmnt`. As an example in */etc/exports*..

```
/media/ketterer/Photos 192.168.122.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

After the change you have to tell the NFS server to pick up the changes.

```
exportfs -ar
```

And finally remount the NFS share at your client.

Comment: /media/ketterer/Photos    192.168.2.0/24
/media/ketterer/Software      192.168.2.0/24

Comment: @JordanKetterer: did you try to add the `crossmnt` option on the NFS server to the exports options? That should do the trick.

Comment: This is the exact answer I needed. For anyone else looking the only thing that I needed to do dirrently is add the line for software rather then photos and then it worked. Thank you so much I tried so many things and thought the problem was with the mount rather then the exports